# Whether to use String or Integer in BigDecimal in Ruby

Tags: ruby, precision, floating-accuracy

Referring to the documentation of `BigDecimal` class,

> `n,m = a.precs`
>   `prec` returns number of significant digits (`n`) and
>   maximum number of significant digits (`m`) of `a`.

I am puzzled by the following output related to `BigDecimal`.

```
require 'bigdecimal'    
BigDecimal.new('1').precs # => [9, 18] 
BigDecimal.new(1).precs   # => [9, 27]
```

I cannot figure out why when a `String` is passed, the maximum number of significant digits is less compared to when a `Fixnum` is passed.

Also will it result in any precision issues?

Comment: The constructor does take a second argument if you want consistency: `BigDecimal.new('1', 27).precs` for example. And the documentation does say that the "number of significant digits is determined from the initial value" if you don't specify it yourself.

Comment: @muistooshort your right that we can specify that. But my question was why the `precs` are different in the first place?

Comment: Here are more data points. The following observations refer to strings containing the character `1` only (e.g., `"111111"`) and numbers whose digits are all `1`'s (e.g., `111111`). For fewer than `10` characters, `[9,18]` is returned. For fewer than `10` digits, `[9,27]` is returned. Between`10` and `18` characters *or* digits, `[18,27]` is returned (i.e., the same tuple is returned for both strings and numbers), between `19` and some greater number of characters or digits, `[27,36]` is returned. Aside: I suggest you add `require 'bigdecimal'` to your code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks for your findings.

Answer (score 4):

If you can read C code, you can start at https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c#L2509 - that's the initializer for any `BigDecimal` object. If you follow that code to the next method, which is [BigDecimal_new](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c#L2545) you'll notice that when passed an integer argument there are a few more steps to go through before allocating and creating an internal big decimal object as opposed to when passing a string argument.

In any case, you shouldn't worry about loss of precision - the significant digits attributes are more like hints than absolute values. Even the documentation mentions it:
[The actual number of significant digits used in computation is usually larger than the specified number.](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-new)